# Put all the services behind the root path on Envoy Proxy

Tags: envoyproxy

I have a series of gRPC services that I would like to put behind Envoy.
However I do not want to put there behind any prefix as it is usual showed in many how-to. I would like to have them all behind the root path `/`. it is my concern to make sure that the endpoint do not collapse together. Is it something achievable in Envoy?

Thank you